# Where we differentiate iphone and ipad programs

Tags: ipad

iam developing one new applciation for ipad.Iam new for ipad.In previous i worked on iphone only.SO please tell me is there any extra code needed for ipad applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good information on [apple's developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

In short:

- iPad has a few extra view controllers for popovers and split views.
- if you choose to make a universal app (Same app that runs on both iPhone and iPad), you have runtime checks to distinguish phone and tablet.